# PEAR path configuration Notice already defined

Tags: pear, config, php, notice

It seems I have a bad pear configuration but can not discover why, I get 'Notice already defined'message when using this library.

On my php.ini I have:

```
.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php
```

the command 'which pear' returns:

```
/usr/bin/pear
```

and the command 'pear config-get php_dir' returns:

```
/usr/share/php/
```

I do not why seems pear to be loading classes twice.

This is how I am using the code:

```
 require_once ('Auth.php');//Pear Auth

       $dns = 'mysql://'.USER.':'.Util::decodePass(PASSWORD).'@'.SERVER.'/'.DBNAME;

       // All options:
       // Use specific username and password columns.
       // Use SHA1() to encrypt the passwords.
       // Retrieve all fields.
       $options = array(
       'dsn' => $dns,
       'table' => 'usuario',
       'usernamecol' => 'login',
       'passwordcol' => 'password',
       'cryptType' => 'md5', //'sha1'
       'db_fields' => '*'
       );

      // Create the Auth object:
      $auth = new Auth('DB', $options, 'show_login_form');

      // Start the authorization:
      $auth->start();

      // Confirm authorization:
      if ($auth->checkAuth()) {
         //Authorized      

              echo(javaScriptRedirect(true,$js));


       } else { // Unauthorized.

         echo(javaScriptRedirect(false,$js));

                //no se valida la autenticacion
       }
```

Comment: please post the full error message you get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notice using PEAR Auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647934/notice-using-pear-auth)